# What's the difference between tf.constant([1,2,3]) and tf.constant([[1,2,3]])

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
>>> tf.constant([1,2,3])
<tf.Tensor 'Const:0' shape=(3,) dtype=int32>
>>> tf.constant([[1,2,3]])
<tf.Tensor 'Const_1:0' shape=(1, 3) dtype=int32>
```

Is `tf.constant([1,2,3])` creating a scalar and `tf.constant([[1,2,3]])` creating an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. `tf.constant([1, 2, 3])` creates a rank 1 constant tensor (a vector). Thus the shape is `(3,)`.

```
>>> sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

>>> tf.constant([1, 2, 3]).eval()
array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

While `tf.constant([[1, 2, 3]])` creates a rank 2 constant tensor (a matrix), with 1 row and 3 columns.. so its shape is `(1, 3)`.

```
>>> tf.constant([[1, 2, 3]]).eval()
array([[1, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

If you really wanted a scalar (rank 0), you wouldn't construct it with a sequence but rather just a scalar value.

```
>>> tf.constant(3)
<tf.Tensor 'Const_5:0' shape=() dtype=int32>
```

Notice the empty shape here, making it clear it is rank 0.

See [Tensor/Rank](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/tensors#rank) in the documentation.